# How do I just run a php script with Ajax (no returns)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to run a php script with ajax. All I want for it to do is just run the script, I don't want any echos or anything. Is there a way to do this. Here is what I've tried:

```
        $('button')[1].click(function () {
          $.ajax({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'like.php',
            data: {
              id: $('button')[1].id
            },
            success: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
            }
          });
```

I thought that this would just run like.php with the get data I sent it but it is not working. I know that the php script works because when I type in the url with the id parameter manually it works.

Comment: I'm sorry, my current code currently does not run the script, or at least not that I know of.

Comment: Did you confirm the ajax is actually firing off? Maybe its your button click handler that is not triggering? Devtools says what?

Comment: The click function was not working. I switched my code to use the onclick attribute and tested it with a log to the console, it is now working

Comment: This should work better: `$('body').on('click','button',function () { .. }`. Although I would highly suggest adding a .class to your "like" buttons. So that the click is not attached to every `button` on the page.

Comment: The clicking now works, the problem is that I don't think the php is running. Perhaps my strategy is not effective?

Comment: Its a fine strategy. I do many fire-n-forget ajax calls for things. Especially click tracking and the like. You just need to debug a bit to see for sure its doing what you want (like check the db for new values, etc). For a like button, you may want to do some post-processing to change the button style, or something, to let the user know when they clicked, it had an effect. But thats beyond the scope here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will clean up and work better for your "fire n forget" like buttons. Add a special class to only the buttons you want to do this:

```
<button class="like-it">I Likes!</button>
```

Then the jquery handler can be this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click','.like-it',function(e){

        e.preventDefault(); // stops the button from doing something else
        $.get(  'like.php',
                { id : $(this).attr('id') },
                function(response) { console.log(response); }
             );

    });
});
```

You can test if your PHP is doing something, by simply returning something and inspecting the result in your console tab of the browser devtools. Since you are ignoring the result, you can echo anything for debugging in devtools. Then comment out the echo when you go to live.

Comment: I echoed "hi" and in the network it says "Failed to load response data." I do think it is going into the php though because it is under the tab: like.php?id=38 which is what the id of the button is. However, it is still not working. When I type in like.php?id=38 as the url manually, it does work

Comment: Might be an issue in chrome (assuming you are using chrome, due to that error). Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38925237/2960971 ... in this case, it might be useful to use `console.log(response);` and a `success` portion. I have updated the answer a bit.

Comment: The response is just all of the html of the page that I'm currently in

Comment: Haha, really? Hmm... I went off the url you provided: `url: 'like.php'` ... unless that php is doing something entirely else? Not sure what to say there, as I have no idea what like.php is doing itself to spit out all your html again. Might be a path issue, url issue, php is including some other php issue... ??

Comment: it was because i redirected back to the original page in the like.php (because originally liking was just sending them to another page and back again). I got rid of it, now there is no response

Comment: NEVER MIND, the response is the hi i echoed. Progress! However, the liking still does not work

Comment: Sounds like its working then... if it went through all that trouble of a redirect. So, that means your ajax calls are golden.

Comment: @IncredibleHat sir there is no need of  `success: function(response)`  , it will work with `function(response)`?

Comment: @KUMAR With the `.get` method, the third param can be a function, and is treated as the success callback. More information can be found on the `.get` man page at jquery: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ ... `.get` is basically a shorthand/alias way of doing the whole shebang. Like `.post`.