# Send Email and Insert from the same form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a page where I have this form that sends the data in an email.
I want that when I click the submit button, other than sending the data through email, I want to send the data in a page where I have an INSERT script.

**Here's the code of my page:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/config.php';

session_start();

if (!empty($_SESSION['_contact_form_error'])) {
    $error = $_SESSION['_contact_form_error'];
    unset($_SESSION['_contact_form_error']);
}

if (!empty($_SESSION['_contact_form_success'])) {
    $success = true;
    unset($_SESSION['_contact_form_success']);
}

?>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Appointmenta</title>

    <!-- reCAPTCHA Javascript -->
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
            <div class="card mt-5">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h1 class="card-title">
                        Add an Appointment
                    </h1>

                    <?php
                    if (!empty($success)) {
                        ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-success">Message sent successfully.</div>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>

                    <?php
                    if (!empty($error)) {
                        ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger"><?= $error ?></div>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>

                    <?php $Field1= $_POST['Field1']; ?>
                    <?php $Field2= $_POST['Field2']; ?>
                    <?php $Field3= $_POST['Field3']; ?>
                    <?php $Field4= $_POST['Field4']; ?>
                    <?php $Field5= $_POST['Field5']; ?>
                    <?php $Field6= $_POST['Field6']; ?>
                    <?php $Field7= $_POST['Field7']; ?>
                    <?php $Field8= $_POST['Field8']; ?>
                    <?php $Field9= $_POST['Field9']; ?>

                    <form id="target" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Field 1</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Field1" id="Field1" class="form-control" 
                                   value="<?php echo $Field1?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="subject">Field 2</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Field2" id="Field2" class="form-control"
                                   value="<?php echo $Field2?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Field 3</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Field3" id="Field3" class="form-control" 
                                   value="<?php echo $Field3?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="subject">Field 4</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Field4" id="Field4" class="form-control"
                                   value="<?php echo $Field4?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="subject">Field 5</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Field5" id="Field5" class="form-control"
                                   value="<?php echo $Field5?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="subject">Field 6</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Field6" id="Field6" class="form-control"
                                   value="<?php echo $Field6?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="subject">Field 7</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Field7" id="Field7" class="form-control"
                                   value="<?php echo $Field7?>">
                        </div>
                   
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="subject">Field 8</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Field8" id="Field8" class="form-control"
                                   value="<?php echo $Field8?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="message">Field 9</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Field9" id="Field9" class="form-control" 
                                   value="<?php echo $Field9?>">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group text-center">
                            <div align="center" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?= CONTACTFORM_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY ?>"></div>
                        </div>

                        <button "name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> Send Email</button>
                    </form>

                    <form action="../list.php">
                        <p><br></p>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Return home.</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script language="Javascript">
<!--

$('form').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'submit.php',
            data: $( this ).serialize()
        });
    });
-->
</script>
```

When I click on 'Send Email' nothing happens.

**I want to click 'Send Email' and see the message 'Message sent successfully'. At the same time I want that same data to be sent to appointment.php, which inserts the data into a table. I'd prefer that 'appointment.php' doesn't even open, I want to stay on index.php when I click 'Send Email'**

**Code of submit.php**

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/functions.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/config.php';

session_start();

// Basic check to make sure the form was submitted.
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
echo "The form must be submitted with POST data.";
exit();
}

require "appointment.php";

// Do some validation, check to make sure the name, email and message are valid.
if (empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
    echo "Please complete the CAPTCHA.";
}

$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha(CONTACTFORM_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY);
$resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_REQUEST['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if (!$resp->isSuccess()) {
    $errors = $resp->getErrorCodes();
    $error = $errors[0];

    $recaptchaErrorMapping = [
        'missing-input-secret' => 'No reCAPTCHA secret key was submitted.',
        'invalid-input-secret' => 'The submitted reCAPTCHA secret key was invalid.',
        'missing-input-response' => 'No reCAPTCHA response was submitted.',
        'invalid-input-response' => 'The submitted reCAPTCHA response was invalid.',
        'bad-request' => 'An unknown error occurred while trying to validate your response.',
        'timeout-or-duplicate' => 'The request is no longer valid. Please try again.',
    ];

    $errorMessage = $recaptchaErrorMapping[$error];
    echo "Please retry the CAPTCHA: ".$errorMessage;
}

// Everything seems OK, time to send the email.

$mail = new \PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = CONTACTFORM_PHPMAILER_DEBUG_LEVEL;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = CONTACTFORM_SMTP_HOSTNAME;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = CONTACTFORM_SMTP_USERNAME;
    $mail->Password = CONTACTFORM_SMTP_PASSWORD;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = CONTACTFORM_SMTP_ENCRYPTION;
    $mail->Port = CONTACTFORM_SMTP_PORT;

    // Recipients
    $mail->setFrom(CONTACTFORM_FROM_ADDRESS, CONTACTFORM_FROM_NAME);
    //$mail->addAddress(CONTACTFORM_TO_ADDRESS, CONTACTFORM_TO_NAME);
    //$mail->addAddress(CONTACTFORM2_TO_ADDRESS, CONTACTFORM2_TO_NAME);
    $mail->addAddress(CONTACTFORM3_TO_ADDRESS, CONTACTFORM3_TO_NAME);
    //$mail->addAddress(CONTACTFORM4_TO_ADDRESS, CONTACTFORM4_TO_NAME);
    //$mail->addReplyTo("marketing@lgp-italia.it");


    // Content
    $mail->Subject = "Appointment at ".$_POST['Field1'];
    $mail->Body    = <<<EOT
    Appointment at:  {$_POST['Field1']},  {$_POST['Field2']}
    {$_POST['Field3']}
    {$_POST['Field4']}
    {$_POST['Field5']}
    {$_POST['Field6']}
    {$_POST['Field7']}

EOT;

    $mail->send();
    
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "An error occurred while trying to send your message: ". $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

**Code of appointment.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    require "../../../security/config.php";
    require "../../../security/common.php";

    try  {
        $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
       
            $new_call = array(
                "Field1"  => $_POST['Field1'],
                 [...]
            );

        echo var_dump("1");

        $sql = sprintf(
                "INSERT INTO %s (%s) values (%s)",
                "db.appointments",
                implode(", ", array_keys($new_call)),
                ":" . implode(", :", array_keys($new_call))
        );

        echo var_dump("2");
        
        $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute($new_call);

        echo var_dump("3");

    } catch(PDOException $error) {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
    }

    echo var_dump("4");
}
    echo var_dump("5");
?>
```

Comment: Did you add jquery in your code ?

Comment: The whole code is up there, also I'm not very familiar with it.

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: Add this some where at the top and then test it

Comment: Nothing happens, as the page just reloads and nothing changes.

Comment: Edit your question and show me what you have updated.

Comment: I've edited the code.

Comment: Instead of two AJAX requests, why not send the data to one PHP script which does both jobs? That would make more sense. Also `async: false` is deprecated, you really should not be using it, it is well known to create a horrible user experience.

Comment: before "code, add https://

Comment: Now my page says: The form must be submitted with POST data.

Comment: Also why are you doing an AJAX and then redirecting to the same page? That makes no sense. The whole point of using AJAX is to avoid doing any reloads, refreshes, redirects or anything like that, and just allow the user to remain on the same page. If you're just going to redirect to the page after you've AJAX'd it, you might as well have just POST-ed the form to that page in the first place, and not bother with AJAX.

Comment: Also, it's unclear - is the code you've shown us in the question part of "submit.php", or another page?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The code is the whole page "index.php", that sends data in the form to submit.php. In appointment.php I put a simple INSERT script to add the data in a table.

Comment: `In appointment.php I put a simple INSERT script to add the data in a table` ...so why not just `require` that from the `submit.php` script, instead of sending a separate AJAX to it?

Comment: `I want to stay on index.php when I click 'Send Email'**` ...don't redirect to submit.php after the AJAX finished, then

Comment: Re your edits: There should be no need to do **any** kind of redirect. That's the **whole point** of using AJAX. Why not just remove that `window.location.href` line entirely? And `window.open("index.php");` makes **no** sense. Why did you change that? Do some **thinking** about the code instead of guessing. Also if you don't want that window to open at all then you need to look back at what I said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67566986/send-email-and-insert-from-the-same-form#comment119427526_67566986)

Comment: You probably want to do _something_ when the AJAX request ends though, like display an acknowledgement message to the user, so they know it submitted ok. So I wouldn't remove the entire "success" block, just alter it. You're still guessing, aren't you? Maybe you need to take a step back and actually familiarise yourself with how AJAX works through some tutorials and practice,  rather than just blundering about hoping you'll eventually find the magic combination of code to make it work.

Comment: Yeah I'm not familiar with it, I'm just kind in a "hurry" let's say. Do you think that the method of requiring appointment.php in submit.php would be easier to do?

Comment: Also for now I just want this to work. Send the email and simultaneously add the data into a table. Then I can work on how to display to the user the success of the work.

Comment: `Do you think that the method of requiring appointment.php in submit.php would be easier to do` it should be easier, and also it removes the need to open another window or send a second request. I can't tell you **exactly** what to do though, because we can't see the code of submit.php or appointment.php here.

Comment: I've added those 2 pages.

Comment: You need to remove all the HTML from appointment.php, but other than that you ought to be able to just `require` it from submit.php. You might want to set a variable which shows if the insert succeeded, then you can use that in the response back to the AJAX request, so it can tell if each part (insert into DB and sending email) was successful, or if any part failed.

Comment: Okay so I've edited appointment.php (took out html) and submit.php (added require appointment.php).Do I really need the ajax request now? Because the button needs to run submit.php and no other pages now.

Comment: You shouldn't need the second AJAX call which sends to appointment.php, no.

Comment: BTW `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` in appointment.php probably isn't going to return true, because there's no "submit" field in your form. You might want to test another field instead, or just test whether it's a POST request generally

Comment: Done that too but it still doesn't do anything.

Comment: `$( "#submit-form" ).click(function() {
  $( "#target" ).submit();
});` is redundant, you don't need that.

Comment: `Done that` ...done what, exactly?

Comment: Also `$('form').submit(function() { $.ajax...` needs to be `$('form').submit(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); $.ajax...` because otherwise it won't prevent the standard postback (and that means the AJAX won't run properly, it will just submit the form back to index.php instead). https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: Took out the second ajax request and added the event.preventDefault(); part

Comment: Ok good. You should be getting somewhere now. Watch your browser's Console and Network tools to spot any problems while you run it, and also ensure you've got PHP and PDO error logging switched on so you can see PHP and SQL errors in the log file, if they occur.

Comment: It gives me: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'  . Also I can see from the network panel that it doesn't arrive to the point of opening submit.php

Comment: Remove the `;` from the end of `$( this ).serialize();`

Comment: Also as I mentioned much earlier, please remove `async: false,`, it's unnecessary and detrimental.

Comment: Removed the ; and async:false but the buttons now seem stuck, I can't click them

Comment: Not clear what "stuck" means exactly? Have you opened the debugging tools as I mentioned? Any feedback from those?

Comment: It means that I click on them, but nothing happens. Also it seems strange to say that but I'll be back in an hour

Comment: Like I said you need to debug with the browser tools

Comment: I made a demo of your client-side code: https://jsfiddle.net/7h9eaw86/ . If you watch the network tool there you'll see it sends the AJAX request correctly. If something is failing on the PHP side in your version, you might see some feedback in the "response" tab of the AJAX request in the Network tool, and/or in the PHP error log (assuming you configured it properly as I advised earlier). You might also find http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/basic-debugging/ useful.

Comment: Now when I click the button nothing shows up like before, so I don't have 'Message sent successfully' coming out, but for now it's not  a problem. The mail is sent and received, but nothing is added to the table in the db.

Comment: `nothing shows up like before` ...because you're not running that code. `Message sent successfully` is part of index.php, but you're not executing index.php, you're executing submit.php. Any output you want to see needs to be a) output from submit.php, and b) captured in your AJAX "success" function and then displayed as appropriate using some Javascript code. That's how AJAX works.

Comment: `nothing is added to the table in the db`...ok and what have you done to try and debug that? Did you make the change I suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67566986/send-email-and-insert-from-the-same-form?noredirect=1#comment119428539_67566986), and also switch on PHP and PDO error logging, before testing it? (Guidance on the setting up the logging can be found [here](https://stackify.com/php-error-logs-guide/) (PHP logs) and [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) (PDO errors)

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to debug and see where it stops

Comment: Also I don't know what redirectWithError() and redirectSuccess() do, but it sounds like they probably try to do a redirect, which won't work in an AJAX context. To adapt this for AJAX usage you need to remove any redirects, and just output any feedback messages directly back to the AJAX code using `echo`.

Comment: But this would solve the problems of giving me errors when sending the email and not when inserting into the db.

Comment: why? You're inserting into the DB in the same script now (via the require) - so any DB errors, you can echo them in appointment.php and they would be combined with the output from submit.php. It would solve both. It really seems you lack some basic knowledge here, both PHP and JavaScript, and maybe the web in general

Comment: So I just replace the redirectWithError() and redirectSuccess() with echo? Also yes I do lack the basis I know, the learning at school wasn't really enough

Comment: Maybe you should do some more tutorials etc then. Anyway for now yes just replace those with an echo or two, to explain the situation to the user. Even if you don't then implement anything in the "success" bit of AJAX yet, you will at least be able to see that output in the Response section of the request in your browser's Network tool, which can help with debugging.

Comment: I've added the echo in those parts, now I'm checking in the response section but it says Failed to Load Response Data

Comment: what HTTP status did you get? There are a few things online about that error already, maybe one of them applies to you: https://www.google.com/search?q=failed+to+load+response+data . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38924798/chrome-dev-tools-fails-to-show-response-even-the-content-returned-has-header-con looks promising, but there are others too.

Comment: I'll check them now. The status it gives me on submit.php is 302 FOUND, while on index.php it gives me 200 OK

Comment: 302 FOUND is a response code you get when the server is trying to tell the browser to redirect. Looks like you didn't remove all the redirects from the PHP.

Comment: I saw that I didn't remove redirectSuccess();, but as I took it out when I click submit it goes on 'Pending'. Nevermind, now everything went through

Comment: The email got sent, I still don't have anything in the response panel but now the status is 200 OK

Comment: You won't get anything in the response panel unless you echo something from submit or appointment

Comment: I've added to appointment echo var_dump($new_call); but I still don't have anything as a response

Comment: Maybe that line doesn't get executed then? You said it still wasn't writing to the DB. Add some more var_dump statements in other places as debugging, so you can see which paths the code does and doesn't take.

Comment: I've added it like 5 times in different part of the code and now I have a response but it gives me NULL

Comment: Well it'll obviously be NULL if you put it in a place where $new_call doesn't exist! Better to make it output some unique text which indicates which place in the code it has passed. Can be as simple as `var_dump("here 1");` in one place and `var_dump("here 2");` in another, etc. so you can tell them apart. Not sure how you expect to work out what's going on if they all try to output the same thing, or try to output things which won't exist in that section of the code? You do need to put a little bit of thought into this, please...being a beginner isn't an excuse for not applying basic logic.

Comment: I added the var dump before only after creating $new_call obviously, just in 5 different places below its creation. Now I have as a response 5, so I know it gets the var_dump from the last line of code

Comment: But there's only one place after it's creation where it would be valid - the line immediately afterwards. Once you get out of the `try` block it would be out of scope.

Comment: Anyway if you want me to help with interpreting your results you're going to have to show where you've put the dumps, and exactly which responses you get, and ensure I'm looking at the latest version of your code. (Just because it gets to the end doesn't mean it passes through all of the places in between which you wanted to.)

Comment: Is that really your latest code? You haven't removed any of the redirects? I can see the dumps in appointment.php though...if you're only seeing "5" out of all of those, then pay attention to this earlier comment I made: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67566986/send-email-and-insert-from-the-same-form?noredirect=1#comment119428539_67566986

Comment: I've uploaded the latest version of appointments.php, although I'll be able to work on it only tomorrow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232524/discussion-between-adyson-and-gigiopasticcio).