# Unable to set headers in nestjs

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config

I am learning nest.js and I am having a hard time setting the response headers..

Here is the code snip

```
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  //@get('users')
  @Get()
  @Header('Content-Type','text/html')
  getHello(): string {
    console.log('log')
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
}
```

I can see the log in the terminal running.
When I open the network tab in google chrome to verify the headers, I don't see anything.

[image: network tab]

I am following this tutorial:: https://youtu.be/F_oOtaxb0L8?t=1530 on youtube

[image: youtubevideo screenshot]

I looked for similar issues on the web and found this :: https://github.com/nestjs/azure-func-http/issues/407

I looked at the documentation and I think I am using everything correctly::
https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#headers

not sure where I am goofing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually doing it correct. It's not related with `nestjs`. It's because of your browser's devtools.

You can confirm it by running in your terminal `curl -v localhost:3000` (If you don't use linux idk, just send a request without your browser and check the headers)

You should see `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` in headers.

You can also disable persist logs and start a new incognito tab and test in the browser tools. For the first response, dev tools should show you the `Content-Type` header. For some reason it does not show it more than once.

For detailed explanation probably [this is a good question to check.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38924798/chrome-dev-tools-fails-to-show-response-even-the-content-returned-has-header-con)

Comment: nice!

I tried it with postman and it worked like a charm!