# Why does Chrome (or Edge) not log the response if it contains a head that changes the location

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, microsoft-edge

Upon requesting GET /, the server sends a 200 response to kickoff an authentication flow.
The body of the response is the following:

```html
<html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" /><script>document.cookie="fragmentAfterLogin="+encodeURIComponent(location.hash)+";path=/";document.cookie="locationAfterLogin="+encodeURIComponent(location.href.split('#')[0].split(location.host)[1])+";path=/";document.cookie="signature=5a0ulnhxPjudu70%2BQCphKEQyZm8%3D;path=/";location="https://authserver.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=sb-na-bea877db-68ab-48d1-1056-c07fd6d0d1bf!t1367&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5005%2Flogin%2Fcallback"</script></head></html>
```

When I look at the Developer tools network trace in either Chrome or Edge, there is no response:

[image]

I had to use `curl` to find out the exact contents of the response. I would expect to see the same response in the network trace.

Comment: Have you select the `Preserve log` option in `Network` tab in devtools? What I want to confirm is if this problem is the same as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38924798/chrome-dev-tools-fails-to-show-response-even-the-content-returned-has-header-con)? Or is it a different problem and are there any specific steps to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Hi @XudongPeng, yes "Preserve log" must be enabled because there are redirects happening. I'm intentionally flagging preserve log because I have an interest in capturing network requests across redirects. Mind blowing to see this issue being stalled (actual status is 'archived' at chromium). Is there a new issue tracking this bug? (Yes it's a bug: I'm flagging "preserve log" and it's not preserving the log...)

Comment: Yes, as mentioned, this is a [known issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=141129). I think you may still need to wait for the official team to provide a solution.