Failed to load response data. No data found with resource with given identifier
i am coding backend for my expense tracker app.
when i click on Submit button, in the network tab, the above error is displayed.
here is the code:
index.js
    const express = require('express')
    const app = express();
    const cors = require('cors');
    const Transaction = require('./models/Transaction.js')
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    require('dotenv').config();
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(express.json());
    app.get('/api/test', (req, res) => {
    res.json('test ok')
    })

    app.post('/api/transaction',async (req, res) => {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
    console.log(process.env.MONGO_URL)
    const { name, description, amount } = req.body;
    const transaction = await Transaction.create({name,description,amount})//Transaction -> model.schema of      DB
    res.json(transaction);

    })

    app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('server is running on port 4000')
    })

the data i am trying to send is not displaying in the mongodb

It seems like a Chrome browser specific issue, as you can see the same issue discussed in the following posts,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38924798/chrome-dev-tools-fails-to-show-response-even-the-content-returned-has-header-con ,
https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40254754 .
Please try the same url from another browser and confirm the issue.
Alternatively please add a statement as console.log(transaction)
just above the statement res.json(transaction). It would help to check the output printed in the server console.

This issue is likely due to a code crash. I recommend debugging your code to identify the problem. In my case, the code crash caused the server to restart, which made the crash difficult to detect.

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
